# Spring4 MVC with Hibernate4 using sessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, sessionfactory

I am making a MVC application using spring 4.1.1 and Hibernate 4.3.6. I want to use sessionfactory.
 Project structure is like this:

[image: project structure is like this]

Dependencies are as shown here using Maven

[image]

my servlet-context is :

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sat.spring">

    </context:component-scan>


    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

My web.xml is as usual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.5" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>  
  index.jsp
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I am running tomcat7 with java1.8.

the problem is in root-context.xml. I suppose it is the applicationContext.xml but named differentley by using

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

on web.xml.

**Edited** root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->    



<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.sat.spring">
            <context:exclude-filter 

expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sat.spring.model" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.sat.spring.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="configLocation"> <props > <prop key="hi"></prop> </props> 
            </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor">
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDao" class="com.sat.spring.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**Edited** my daoImpl  now is :

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {       

    /*  
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }*/

        //private SessionFactory sessionFactory;    

        public int save(User user) {

        /*  // saving implementation goes here
                    String query = "insert into student values('" + s.getId() + "','" + s.getName() + "','" + s.getFee() + "','"
                            + s.getDepartment() + "')";

                    System.out.println("--inside save employee---" + query);*/      

            /*String query = "insert into USER values('" + user.getId() + "','" + user.getName() + "')";

            System.out.println("Indise USER" + query);   */     

            return 0;
        }    
    }
```

As suggested I have added jdbc.properties file in web

```
#jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
#jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
#jdbc.username=admin
#jdbc.password=admin     

# MYSQL Driver
jdbc.driverClassName =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.databaseurl =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uniprojectdb
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root

# postgRdb
#jdbc.driverClassName =com.postgress.jdbc.Driver
#jdbc.databaseurl =jdbc:post://localhost:3306/devdb
#jdbc.username=post
#jdbc.password=post
```

when I run it now I get the following error on console from Tomcat:

```
    Oct 14, 2016 3:54:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\xampp\mysql\bin\;C:\Python34;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\\bin; C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;B:\STS\sts-bundle\sts-3.7.1.RELEASE;;.
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:UniversityProject08' did not find a matching property.
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVCJdbc03' did not find a matching property.
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1111 ms
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:06 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [124] milliseconds.
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:06 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(B:\UniversityProject-STS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\SpringMVCJdbc03\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-7.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:08 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:08 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 14 15:54:08 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:08 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/application-config.xml]
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:09 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:09 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 903 ms
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:09 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:09 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 15:54:09 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:09 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml]
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/save],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.save(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/registered],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.registered(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/option],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.option(com.spring.model.Student,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/viewstudent],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.viewStudent()
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/deleteStudent],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.deletStudent(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/studentform],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.showform()
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/deletedStudent],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.dele(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/editStudent],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.edit(com.spring.model.Student)
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerHandlerMethod
INFO: Mapped "{[/edit],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.spring.controllers.StudentController.editStudent(int,com.spring.model.Student,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:10 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 967 ms
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 14 15:54:13 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [jdbc.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN : org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2697 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 15:54:15 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sat.spring.controller.HomeController.home()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[//home],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sat.spring.controller.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.sat.spring.controller.LoginController.login()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/submit],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sat.spring.controller.LoginController.saveOrUpdateUser(com.sat.spring.model.User,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 15:54:15 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Oct 14 15:54:15 EDT 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 729 ms
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11403 ms
Oct 14, 2016 3:54:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/spring] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist] with root cause
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.sat.spring.controller.LoginController.saveOrUpdateUser(LoginController.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

INFO : org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@124d1985: startup date [Fri Oct 14 15:54:25 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
```

Thanks...

Comment: Have you looked at Spring Boot and the Spring Initializer?  Spring boot allows you to "bootstrap" all of the configuration that you have listed above and lets you get straight to the development.  Also, there are a ton of guides and help out there.  http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Comment: Have you defined the value of `${hibernate.dialect}` somewhere? I can't find it in what you have posted. So is the case with `${jdbc.driverClassName}`, `${jdbc.url}`, `${jdbc.user}`, etc.  If not, you will have to provide valid values for these property variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your datasource configuration. The property placeholder values are not being resolved. Check the error here

**WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class '${jdbc.driverClassName}'**

You need to define a properties file containing the property placheolder values e.g

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
```

jdbc.properties will be in the root of your classpath containing the values

Because of the error in your datasource config Hibernate can not get the connection to determine the dialect to use hence the error

**Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null**

Comment: I added the jdbc.properties file in src/main/resources and I am getting the above error[edited version]...

Comment: You need to have a mysql JDBC driver in order to connect to your database. Add the folowing dependency to your pom.xml  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.40</version>
</dependency>

Comment: added the mySQL connector for jdbc

Comment: now I get this SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/spring] threw exception .....
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist.